# Correct way to add users to a Subversion repository

Tags: subversion, accounts

I want to make sure I don't corrupt my Subversion repository.

If I need to add a new user to a repostiory, I would add them to the `svnserve.conf` under `/conf` for each repository correct?

If this is true, when do I use `svnadmin`.

Also the `README.TXT` file also says to use `svnadmin`, or otherwise there could be complications. This is why I'm paranoid and want to make sure I do no harm.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you are not pre-authorizing using `ssh`, you can tell `svnserve` which file has the user credentials.

Your `svnserve.conf` file would contain a `password-db` entry which points to a file with the user and passwords:

```
[general]
password-db = userpass
realm = yourcomp
```

And the `userpass` would have:

```
[users]
larry.user = mypassword
barry.user = hispassword
```

There is nothing that says that multiple repositories cannot use the same password-db file.
Refer to [Redbook section on svnserve.conf](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.serverconfig.svnserve.html)

Using `svnadmin` is not necessary.